# preferences android error

Tags: android

i have a problem with this line,eclipse wrote to me "addPreferencesFromResource is undefined for the MainActivity" and wrote error for me at this line:

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
```

also i import:

```
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.preference.EditTextPreference;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
```

how can i fix it?

thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addPreferenceFromResource` is a `PreferenceActivity` method. Make sure your MainActivity extends it.

Comment: no i forgot do it...and how can i extand multiple method: Activity and PreferenceActivity ? java doesnt allow tome to extands both...

Comment: you can't. But you also do not need to. Extend `PreferenceActivity` only

Comment: thanks, i also need help with this tutorial: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-quick-preferences-tutorial.html     i dont understand what is the "R.layout.show_settings_layout" and how do i need to create it?

Comment: show_settings_layout is the basic layout to show the result of editing preferences. If this seems obscure, start with a more generic android tutorial before seeing preferences